# KDoc: change parameters order

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I have the following parameters in a *companion object* on Kotlin

```
    companion object Constants {
    /**
     * Values for the various type of connection that a device can have.
     */
    const val CONNECTION_KEY = "Connection_type"
    const val CONNECTION_AUX = "AUX"
    const val CONNECTION_BLUETOOTH = "Bluetooth"
    const val CONNECTION_USB = "USB"

    /**
     * Unique IDs respectively for devices and media elements.
     */
    const val DEVICE_ID_KEY = "Device_ID"
    const val MEDIA_ID_KEY = "Media_ID"

    /**
     * Various keys that you can find in [Bundle] returned by [getMediaItems].
     */
    const val MEDIA_NAME_KEY = "Media_name"
    const val SONG_IDS_KEY = "Songs_ids"
    const val GENRE_IDS_KEY = "Genres_ids"
    const val ARTIST_IDS_KEY = "Artists_ids"
}
```

The problem is that, in *Kdoc* results, I find them in *alphabetical* order

> ARTIST_IDS_KEY
>
> const val ARTIST_IDS_KEY: String
>
> CONNECTION_AUX
>
> const val CONNECTION_AUX: String
>
> CONNECTION_BLUETOOTH
>
> const val CONNECTION_BLUETOOTH: String
>
> CONNECTION_KEY
>
> Values for the various type of connection that a device can have.
>
> const val CONNECTION_KEY: String
>
> CONNECTION_USB
>
> const val CONNECTION_USB: String
>
> DEVICE_ID_KEY
>
> Unique IDs respectively for devices and media elements.
>
> const val DEVICE_ID_KEY: String
>
> GENRE_IDS_KEY
>
> const val GENRE_IDS_KEY: String
>
> MEDIA_ID_KEY
>
> const val MEDIA_ID_KEY: String
>
> MEDIA_NAME_KEY
>
> Various keys that you can find in Bundle returned by getMediaItems.
>
> const val MEDIA_NAME_KEY: String
>
> SONG_IDS_KEY
>
> const val SONG_IDS_KEY: String

... is there a way to mantain original order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group elements in *kDoc* by grouping them in the *code*:

```
companion object Constants {
    /**
     * Values for the various type of connection that a device can have.
     */
    object Connection {
        const val KEY = "Connection_type"
        const val AUX = "AUX"
        const val BLUETOOTH = "Bluetooth"
        const val USB = "USB"
    }

    /**
     * Unique IDs respectively for devices and media elements.
     */
    object IDs {
        const val DEVICE = "Device_ID"
        const val MEDIA = "Media_ID"
    }

    /**
     * Various keys that you can find in [Bundle] returned by [getMediaItems].
     */
    object BundleKeys {
        const val MEDIA_NAME = "Media_name"
        const val SONG_IDS = "Songs_ids"
        const val GENRE_IDS = "Genres_ids"
        const val ARTIST_IDS = "Artists_ids"   
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, you where very useful. Do you know how can I access these objects from Java?

Comment: @Lore You can either `import packagename.OuterClass.Constants;` and use `Constants.Connection.KEY`, remove `companion` modifier and use `OuterClass.Constants.Connection.KEY` or move these nested objects out of companion object to `OuterClass` and use `OuterClass.Connection.KEY`.